# how to use custom tag with flask wtf?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, ionic-framework, flask-wtforms

I Am trying to make a simple web app with Flask and Ionic. I added Ionic CDN links in my templates.

But there is a problem with my code. I tried to use 'ion-input' with 'Flask-wtf', But I can't find a way to use it.

Flsk-wtf code:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, TextField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class Name(FlaskForm):
    """Name form."""
    name = StringField('Name', [
        DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

After passing the Name class from app.py,

I used it on html:

```
<body>
<ion-app>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-item>
        {{ form.name }}
        {{ form.submit }}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-content> 
</ion-app>
</body>
```

Is it possible to use 'ion-input' with Wtf?

Please Forgive my poor grammar.

Comment: Does this not work?  What error do you see?

Comment: @GAEfan There is no error. Works fine, But i want to add the  'ion-input' to match the theme.

Comment: Is `ion-input` a tag (i.e. <ion-input>) or an attribute (i.e. <input type="text" ion-input>)?

Comment: if ion-input is a class, you can add it like this: {{ form.name(class_="ion-input") }}. Else (as S N asked), you might need to write your own field renderer (jinja macro possibly). It would help to showcase your desired HTML code output :)

Comment: '<ion-input>' is a tag. Please provide some information or example code, About 'how to write Custom field renderer?'